# Move to first screen/Home screen at Application Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

  NSLog(@"Application is terminating now.");
}
```

This function is called when application is going to be terminated and i have added this just to add some lines of code to my question. In iOS when an application crashes at some stage and we have not handle that case properly, it will set the user to move to main screen (outside from that crashed application).
In android, i have seen in most of the applications if a person have not handle the crashing scenario it sets the user to move to home screen.
There should be any method that is going to be called when a crash occur and we can call the firstView at that stage.
I have not find that method/delegate so far in objective c/swift.
If anyone knows, you can answer here.
Note: Please don't suggest to use

```
@try {

 } @catch (NSException *exception) {

} @finally {

}
```

as i'm asking in the sense that i have handle almost all the exception scenarios properly but asking in the case if some scenario fails or some other issue an application crashes on any device what is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch exceptions causing crashes with `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` like so:

```
func exceptionHandler(exception : NSException) {
   // Do something before the app is automatically terminated
   print(exception.callStackSymbols)
}

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler)
```

This handler will be called right after the crash and before the app is force-closed.
You won't be able to stop the application from crashing but at least you can get the call stack and use it for logging and finding out what happened!

Comment: Now thats interesting. This is giving the reason of exception and thanks for the reply but still waiting a kind of answer that can stop the application from crashing.

Comment: As Bali mentioned it is not possible to stop the application from crashing. When an unhandled exception is raised, the system takes over and leaves you with no choice other than looking it crash.

Comment: Yes, i have searched a lot and in the end now i have to accept your answer becuase i found no workaround so far.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that in ios. the delegate `applicationWillTerminate` is called just before the app is terminating. There you cant avoid the app termination. Once the `applicationWillTerminate` is called, the app will terminate. The only way you can avoid crashing is to find out the issue & solving it. You can catch memory warnings in `didRecieveMemoryWarning` and you can catch exceptions in code which will give you some of the problems that causes crashes before crashing

Comment: yes, i know. I have add this just to add some line of code in my question. I'm asking is there any workoround?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way you can avoid that other than solving your crash issue